# Возможно ли в веб плеере проигрывать видео стрим формата MPEG-TS (MPEG-2 Transport Stream)?

Tags: javascript, html5, flash, видео

Возможно ли через flash/html5 проигрывать стрим такого формата?

Comment: а гугл что говорит об этом?

Comment: @norbornen я не смог найти в гугле рабочего решения

Comment: так пишут же что невозможно

Comment: Про то что совсем уж не возможно меня смущает наличие такой библиотеки: https://github.com/RReverser/mpegts

Но у меня заставить проигрывать mpegts стримы не получилось.

Comment: перекодировать на клиенте? однако...

Comment: Как я понял, https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls, перекодировывает на клиенте HLS во Flash. И результат вполне себе приемлемый. Вдруг и с mpegts есть рабочие решения.

Comment: понятно... а если проксировать поток через свой сервер с одновременной перекодировкой?